# How can I update a manifest version 2 to a manifest version 3?

Tags: manifest

My Manifest is a MV2 and I don't know how to update it to a MV3.

{"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx", "version": "0.1.9.12", "name": "**MSG_extName**", "description": "**MSG_extDesc**", "default_locale": "en", "offline_enabled": true, "chrome_url_overrides": {"newtab": "/start/index.html"}, "background": {"persistent": true, "scripts": ["bd2989e2.js", "/start/chrome/settings.js", "/start/common/prefs-sys.js", "/start/chrome/utils.js", "/start/common/default-whitelist.js", "/start/chrome/background.js"]}, "content_scripts": [{"all_frames": false, "run_at": "document_end", "js": ["/start/search/content-homepage.js"], "matches": ["https://*.freeaddon.com/*"]}], "browser_action": {"default_icon": {"128": "start/skin/icons/128.png", "16": "start/skin/icons/16.png", "48": "start/skin/icons/48.png"}}, "icons": {"128": "start/skin/icons/128.png", "16": "start/skin/icons/16.png", "48": "start/skin/icons/48.png"}, "web_accessible_resources": ["start/skin/*"], "permissions": ["https://*.freeaddon.com/*", "https://suggestqueries.google.com/*", "unlimitedStorage", "topSites", "management", "<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"], "manifest_version": 2}